# mongo-go-driver (IndexNotFound) text index required for $text query

Tags: mongodb, go, indexing, text-search

I'm using mongo-go-driver and trying to use text search

I'm creating index like this

```
    opts := options.CreateIndexes().SetMaxTime(10 * time.Second)
    db.Collection("my_collection").Indexes().CreateMany(
        context.Background(),
        []mongo.IndexModel{
            {
                Keys: bsonx.Doc{{"title", bsonx.Int32(-1)}},
            },
            {
                Keys: bsonx.Doc{{"info.tags", bsonx.Int32(-1)}},
            },
        },
        opts,
    )
```

...and while querying I'm doing this

```
    collection := db.Collection("my_collection")

    cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{ "$text": bson.M{ "$search": query }})
```

I get this when I call the query

```
 (IndexNotFound) text index required for $text query
  exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a [**`text`** index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) on atleast 1 field for the query to work.
Try creating a text index on any field and try again

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most